# Release File Lock on OES2

Tags: novell

In the past with NetWare we could use Remote Manager to see what user had a file locked, and clear the connection. How is this accomplished for an NSS volume hosted on OES2 Linux?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the 'ncpcon' command from the command-line. The interface isn't nearly as good as NRM, but at least it is there. There may be other ways.

Comment: we had to recover a file from salvage, and it shows being locked by NDSD. kind of annoying actually.

Answer (score 1):

This actually CAN be done in NORM, its just not intuitive. You can find it under manage NCP shares then click on the I icon where you've usually find the inventory information.

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in to Remote Manager
2. Manage NCP Services
3. Manage Shares
4. Click on the "information" icon in front of the volume name
5. Click the "Open File Information" button
6. This will show all the open files, and you can search by name for
   the one in question
7. When you find it, click the "Close" button next to it